# Canadian citizenship for adopted person

Tags: canada, citizenship

I am working on getting Canadian citizenship for our daughter who we are in the process of adopting (bolivia). Part 1 of the process is yo confirm the ability to pass on our citizenship and that has been submitted. They won't tell you what documents are needed until we are approved for part 2, but it is easier to get copies during the adoption process than it is afterward. Anyone know what documents they ask for for part 2 of the process?

Comment: What is part 2 of the process?

Comment: There seems to be a list here https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/application/application-forms-guides/guide-0014-application-canadian-citizenship-person-adopted-canadian-citizen-part-2-adoptee-application.html

Answer (score 1):

This page provides [a list of the documents required in part 2 of the process](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/application/application-forms-guides/guide-0014-application-canadian-citizenship-person-adopted-canadian-citizen-part-2-adoptee-application.html)

The list is too long to quote in full here, but a summary is:

- Part 2 – Adoptee’s Application
  CIT 0012, completed, dated and signed.
- Two pieces of the adopted person’s personal identification
- documents supporting the adoption
- birth certificate of adoptee, and also the death certificate of adoptee's parents if applicable
- Two identical citizenship application photographs of the adopted person
- documentation proving legal guardianship (if the legal guardian is applying for Canadian citizenship on behalf of the adopted person);
- documentation to support a date of birth correction, if applicable
  For more information. See: “Date of birth correction” in this section.
- Use of a Representative form (IMM 5476), if applicable (original)